# Смешивание и умножение значений в массиве

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

```
 var bets = [
               {img: "img1", name: "Геннадий"},
               {img: "img2", name: "Геннадий"},
               {img: "img3", name: "Геннадий"}];
```

Есть вот такой массив, из этого массива надо сделать что-то типо этого:

```
               <span>img3</span>
               <span>img2</span>
               <span>img1</span>
               <span>img3</span>
               <span>img2</span>
               <span>img2</span>
               <span>img3</span>
               <span>img2</span>
               <span>img1</span>
               <span>img1</span>
               <span>img2</span>
               <span>img3</span>
               <span>img2</span>
               <span>img1</span>
               <span>img1</span>
               <span>img3</span>
```

Нужно чтобы img повторялось 5 раз, а потом рандомно смешивалось со всеми остальными значениями.

Comment: Что конкретно не позволяет вам сделать это на `JavaScript`?

Comment: jquery вариант нужен

Comment: Задача `jQuery` - управлять DOM-ом. Не представляю что вы подразумеваете под "jquery вариантом". В любом случае, у вас и "обычного" варианта нет. Чем вы хотите чтобы вам помогли?

Comment: В данном случае, я достаточно много посмотрел примеров реализации, но ни один не подходит под мою задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала создаем по 5 копий каждого элемента, потом перемешиваем их и добавляем куда вам нужно, всё просто:

```js
var bets = [
   {img: "img1", name: "Геннадий"},
   {img: "img2", name: "Геннадий"},
   {img: "img3", name: "Геннадий"}
];

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

var items = [];
for( var key in bets) {
    var item = bets[key];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        items.push($('<span>').text(item.img));
    }
}

items = shuffle(items);

for(var key in items) {
      var el = items[key];
      $(el).appendTo('.items');
}
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items"></div>
```

В исходном коде отобразит то что вам надо.